# PHP returns ContentType text/html when function returns json

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am attempting to get a JSON string back from a php call (from javascript).  I do something similar in another function that works fine (except I am returning multiple records and calling as the ajax:  component of a DataTable (datatables.net) and am not using bind in that function.  I don't think my issue is with query / OCI.  The query works fine in Toad, and I am using the same code for making the DB connection as in the routine that works.

php code:

```php
require 'openDB.php';
if (!$ora ) {
    return "COULD NOT CONNECT to DB";
}
$rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
$params = json_decode($rawJson);
$action = $params['action'];
$jobID = $params['jobID'];

if ($action == 'read') {
    return $jobID;
    //readMaintenanceData($ora, $jobID);
} else if ($action == 'update') {
    updateMaintenanceData();
} else if ($action == 'add') {
    addJob();
} else if ($action == 'delete') {
    deleteJob();
}

function readMaintenanceData($ora, $jobID) {
   
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (! $ora) {
   
        return "COULD NOT CONNECT";
    }
    $getJob = oci_parse(
    $ora, 
    "SELECT JOB_ID, JOB_DESCRIPTION,  INFO_DISTRIBUTION, ACTIVE, JOB_RUNNING_SERVER "
    ."FROM SCRPT_APP.JOB_MONITOR_JOBS "
    ."WHERE JOB_ID = :jobID"
);
 
    oci_bind_by_name($getJob, ':jobID', $jobID);
    oci_execute($getJob);
    $job = oci_fetch_array($getJob, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
   
    $job_jason =  json_encode($job);
   
    return $job_jason;
}

function updateMaintenanceData() {}
function addJob() {}
function deleteJob() {}
```

'''' javascript

```
async function populateMaintenanceTab() {

var url = "php/maintenance.php";
 var jobID = document.getElementById('jobID').value;
//alert(jobID);
//var rBody = 'action=read&jobID=' + encodeURIComponent(jobID);
const getJob = {
    action: 'read',
    jobID: jobID
};

fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(getJob),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});



}
```

Here is the js state at the time I call fetch (note:  control does transfer to the php but the $_POST variable is not populated)

[image]

Many thanks to Phil for his efforts to date.

Comment: You seem to be trying to read `jobID` before it is defined in your JS code

Comment: What does the response actually look like in your dev-tools _Network_ console? Also, if you want the JSON data from your response, you should `return response.json()`

Comment: Thanks, Phil.  You are correct on both counts:  However fixing those issues still gets the same response when the test for content type is enabled.  However, now when I disable that test, I get the following error message (from the catch):  Syntax Error:  Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Comment: **What does the response actually look like in your [browser] dev-tools Network console?**

Comment: Headers:  General
Request URL: http://localhost/JobMonitor/php/maintenance.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 22:54:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/8.0.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.1

Comment: request Headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/JobMonitor/index.php
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.74

Request Payload:
action=read&jobID=BULK FILE LOAD (expected)

Comment: Under Response it says:  Failed to load Response Data

Comment: It's extremely difficult to debug this via proxy through comments. Please include screenshots from your Network console. Also (and this in no way precludes my asking for screenshots), if your `jobID` value contains spaces, you should probably encode it correctly, eg `var rBody = 'action=read&jobID=' + encodeURIComponent(jobID)`

Comment: In short, your PHP script is responding with an HTML document, probably from an error. You should be able to see this response in your browser's Network dev-tool. You could also use something like `curl` to test the response directly, eg `curl -d "action=read" -d "jobID=BULK+FILE+LOAD" -v "http://localhost/JobMonitor/index.php"`

Comment: The response is null.  (See my edits to the post)

Comment: I have made some progress.  I now get a 'promise' return, but the ultimate results are the same and the $_POST values are still not populated in my php script.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem but shouldn't content-type be `application/json` and not `application.json`?

Comment: `$_POST` is not populated for `application/json` request. You need to parse the request content reading from `php://input`. Anyway the response is empty: is `readMaintenanceData` function actually called?

Comment: imvain2:  You are correct the application.json was a typo.  I have corrected that (see current code above)

Alessandro:  I had high hopes for your solution, but I get the same result.  xDebug was working in Netbeans for me the other day but now netbeans hangs on connecting to xDebug.  Previously, though I was able to verify that I was getting to the php code.  I will try to resolve my xDebug issue (again)

Comment: The answer from dave is correct: you need to pass `true` as second parameter of `json_decode` to be able to use the result as array. You should enable `error_reporting` for all kinds of error to see if there’s no error. Anyway you need to `echo` the response, not just return it.

Comment: @MarkAinsworth please stop changing the goal posts on this one. All you had to do was inspect the actual response body and no, it was **not** _"null"_. If it was, you wouldn't have gotten that unexpected token error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've touched PHP, so this could be inaccurate, but I'm pretty sure `json_decode` returns an object unless you pass in true as the second parameter, so

```
$rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
$params = json_decode($rawJson);
$action = $params['action'];
```

should be either

```
$rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
$params = json_decode($rawJson);
$action = $params->action;
```

or

```
$rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
$params = json_decode($rawJson, true);
$action = $params['action'];
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  At first I did not see a change but adding some debug 'echo's' in php revealed that I am able to parse the request.